# Нужен совет по необычному SQL-запросу из PHP

Tags: sql

В таблице БД `apartments` площадь квартиры хранится в строке `square` по следующему шаблону: *«общая-жилая-кухня». Таким образом, это выглядит как `32-28-6`.

Теперь стоит вопрос: как сформировать SQL-запрос, если нужно вывести только общую площадь не менее нужного значения? Я понимаю, что задача не простая, но база уже наполнена объявлениями, и в систему поиска предстоит добавить только этот функционал, не нарушая работы остальных участков кода проекта.

До какого-то момента я использовал ошибочный запрос (но это не вариант):

```
SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE square LIKE '30-%'
```

Средства PHP задействовать можно, но здесь в самом запросе идет уже деление на страницы через `LIMIT`. Таким образом, если после получения результатов поиска мы будем отбирать «нужные» по площади квартиры, то у нас на одной странице получится 10 записей, а на другой меньше или вообще ничего.

**Ребята, большое ВАМ спасибо за оперативное решение сложного для меня вопроса!
Особенно благодарен пользователям *cache* и *Akina* - ваше решение успешно работает!**

Comment: Возможно стоит решить эту задачу не средствами SQL а средствами PHP ?

Comment: обрезаете подстроку, переводите в число, сравниваете с требуемым

Comment: А SQL у вас какой ? тут нужны строковые функции, а в разных СУБД они разные.

Comment: Для MySql `SELECT * FROM apartments a WHERE (0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(square, '-' , 1)) >= 30`

Comment: Всё верно. А у него MySQL или клон - больше нигде LIMIT и лёгкий интерфейс из PHP не засветился вроде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM apartments 
WHERE 0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(square,'-',1) >= 30;
```

Comment: А как с точки зрения производительности лучше делать приведение типов? неявно через сложение или явно привести к числу `WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(square, '-' , 1) AS SIGNED) >= 30` ?

Comment: Я думаю, что в обоих случаях приведения как такового не будет, у MySQL нестрогая типизация всё-таки. Да, явный CAST не имеет оверхеда в виде дополнительного явного сложения - но опять же вряд ли это можно отловить в бенчмарках... Кстати, а почему беззнаковое? И ещё задумайся - а, может, корректнее сравнивать как строки? **WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(square,'-',1) >= '30'**? если первое число будет 200 - его надо включать в вывод или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно имеет смысл воспользоваться наличием дефиса. Все три значения чисел выделяются следующим образом.

1.дефис слева

2.дефис слева и справа

3.дефис справа

В данном случае извлекаем 3 вариант.

```
    $value = 30;
    $max = 100;
      for (int i = $value; i < $max; i++) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE square LIKE   '.$value.'- ',$db) or die('error! Записей не найдено!');

     //проверяем, есть ли результат, что-то делаем с результатом, собираем в массив к примеру
      }
```

как еще один вариант

```
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM apartments WHERE square LIKE   '%-%-%',$db) or die('error! Записей не найдено!');
    while ($rows=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
     $arraySubString[] = split("-", $rows[n], 3);//n - требуемый столбец
     if($arraySubString[0] >=  $value ){
     //что-то делаем с $rows, собираем или выводим, к примеру
     $arraySubString[]= array();//обнуляем массив
    }
```

Comment: автор же пишет, что ему надо достать не тридцатиметровые квартиры, а квартиры от тридцати метров и больше

Comment: @Etki Спасибо за уточнение, немного подправил. В случае критики готов удалить сие решение.

Comment: да удалять не надо (сюда по запросу из гугла легко может прийти человек, которому нужно точное совпадение), но у текущего варианта количество запросов растет как O(n), а можно обойтись простым O(1). Вся магия в общем-то сводится к трем действиям - вычленить первый элемент (просто подстрокой или регэкспом), превратить его в число (каст), сравнить с предоставленным. Если распишете этот алгоритм - будет круто.